# TPLink TL-WN7200ND wireless not working well in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, ubuntu-drivers

I have a tp-link wireless usb TL-WN7200ND. I just tested out the speed of my connection on Speedtest.net and it only shows up to half of my speed. I tried testing the speed in Windows 7 and its working like it should be. This tells me that this is an issue with Ubuntu and this specific wireless device. Any solutions on how it get it working properly in Ubuntu?

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1058:1001 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. External Hard  Disk [Elements]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04ca:006d Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: lsusb  Welcome to askubuntu!